# Exchange Server 2010 OWA "Couldn't find a base theme"

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I have a Exchange Server 2010 Enterprise Edition on windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.  When I try to login to OWA, I receive the following error:

```
Outlook web app didn't initialize. If the problem continues please contact
your helpdesk. 

Couldn't find a base theme (folder name=base)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Install SP1 if it isn't already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the themes in your OWA folder. The default location should be:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\Owa\Current\themes
```

There's 29 themes installed by default, one of them being "base."  Reinstalling Exchange may be in order. As Chris said above, installing SP1 will help as well if you haven't already.

Answer (score 6):

All you only need to:

1. Open Exchange Management Shell (EMS)-run as administrator.
2. Copy and paste the following code into EMS:

   `cd to ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin’`
3. Run UpdateCas.ps1

   `UpdateCas.ps1`

That’s it! OWA folders will be populated with the required files again and voila! OWA is back online.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the rollup 11 for exchange 2010 sp3 (kb3078674), you must deinstall it. In my case it solved my problem.